# How do I add items to join tables in Rails? Do they get their own models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models: `Reader` and `Magazine`. I obviously want to have a join table, `readers_magazines`, to represent which magazines each reader is subscribed to.

So I create my `Reader` model (with fields like `name`, `address` and `age`) and my `Magazine` model (with fields like `Title` and `Active?`). In each model I write `has_and_belongs_to_many` of the other.

Then I write a migration, `CreateReadersMagazinesJoin`, and write:

```
create_join_table :readers, :magazines do |t|
  t.index 'reader_id'
  t.index 'magazine_id'
end
```

And migrate the database. All good.

My question is... what now? Do I create a model for the join table? That seems wrong, and yet I do need some model validations (I don't want to represent the same User-Subscription combo twice). So do I write a model for it and manually specify the database table to use?

What is the correct procedure in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

From the [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)s:

> A has_and_belongs_to_many association creates a direct many-to-many
>   connection with another model, with no intervening model.

That means that using a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association might be easier for you to setup (because there is no middle model) but you don't have any kind of control over the join table, validations, etc. HABTM are normally considered harmful and you would want to use a `has_many :through` relationship instead, that is the same but having a model to represent the join table, so you have control over everything.

More information [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

Answer (score 0):

> Do I create a model for the join table? That seems wrong, and yet I do need some model validations.

If you don't want to add an additional fields to the join table, you don't really need to create the model for it.

And in most cases the validation that are required by yours, can be applied to one or both the tables.

> I don't want to represent the same User-Subscription combo twice.

What do you mean twice, I havent seen the cases for that, however since the `User`-`Subscription` is something external the for the join table, you can explain more crear.

Comment: By twice, I mean that any combination of `User`-`Subscription` should appear only once. That is, when Sarah subscribes to Cats Weekly, a line in the join table would be `Sarah`-`Cats Weekly`, and if I try to add an identical line it would be rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have the choice between a habtm relationship or separate model, I would consider whether you need a rich amount of data in the join. In the present case, I think you do need extra data in the join. For example, a subscription would have a start date and an end date. It may also have a billing date and billing amount. You would not normally populate this information in a join table but rather in a stand alone model.

Answer (score 0):

I would call the join table `subscriptions` and thus create a model `Subscription`. Then you can do it like this:

```
class Reader < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :magazines, through: :subscriptions
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  beongs_to :reader
  belongs_to :magazine
end

class Magazine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :readers, through: :subscriptions
end
```